# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to run a simple spark to s3 app from a server but I keep getting the below error because the server has hadoop 2.7.3 installed and it looks like it doesn't include the [GlobalStorageStatistics class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/GlobalStorageStatistics.html). I have hadoop 2.8.x defined in my pom.xml file but trying to test it by running it locally.

How can I make it ignore searching for that or what workaround options are there to include that class if I have to go with hadoop 2.7.3?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.hasMetadata(DataSource.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:425)
    at com.ibm.cos.jdbc2DF$.main(jdbc2DF.scala:153)
    at com.ibm.cos.jdbc2DF.main(jdbc2DF.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.StorageStatistics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I had similar issues and a working more up to date example with current version numbers that work together can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592717/458370

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't mix bits of Hadoop and expect things to work. It's not just the close coupling between internal classes in hadoop-common and hadoop-aws, its things like the specific version of the amazon-aws SDK the hadoop-aws module was built it.

If you get `ClassNotFoundException` or `MethodNotFoundException` stack traces when trying to work with `s3a://` URLs, JAR version mismatch is the likely cause.

Using the RFC2117 MUST/SHOULD/MAY terminology, here are the rules to avoid this situation:

1. The s3a connector is in hadoop-aws JAR; it depends on hadoop-common and the aws-sdk-shaded JARs.
2. all these JARs MUST be on the classpath.
3. All versions of the hadoop-* JARs on your classpath MUST be *exactly* the same version, e.g 3.3.1 everywhere, or 3.2.2. Otherwise: stack trace. Always
4. And they MUST be *exclusively of that version*; there MUST NOT be multiple versions of hadoop-common, hadoop-aws etc on the classpath. Otherwise: stack trace. Always. Usually `ClassNotFoundException` or `MethodNotFoundException` indicating a mismatch in hadoop-common and hadoop-aws.
5. The exact missing classes/methods vary across Hadoop releases: it's the first class depended on by `org.apache.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` which the classloader can't find -the exact class depends on the mismatch of JARs
6. The AWS SDK jar SHOULD be the huge aws-java-sdk-bundle JAR, unless you know exactly which bits of the AWS SDK stack you need *and are confident all transitive dependencies (jackson, httpclient, ...) are in your Spark distribution *and* compatible. Otherwise: missing classes or odd runtime issues.
7. There MUST NOT be any other v1 AWS SDK jars on your classpath. Otherwise: duplicate classes and general classpath problems. Note: AWS v1 and v2 SDKs can coexist as they use completely different classes in different packages.
8. The AWS SDK version SHOULD be the one shipped. Otherwise: maybe stack trace, maybe not. Either way -you are in self-support mode or have opted to join a QE team for version testing.
9. The specific version of the AWS SDK you need can be determined from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws)
10. Changing the AWS SDK versions MAY work. You get to test, and if there are compatibility problems: you get to fix. See [Qualifying an AWS SDK Update](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/testing.html#Qualifying_an_AWS_SDK_Update) for the least you should be doing.
11. The AWS v1 and v2 SDKs are completely different. If the wrong one is on your classpath for the hadoop version you are using, expect ClassNotFoundExceptions.
12. You SHOULD use the most recent versions of Hadoop you can/Spark is tested with. Non-critical bug fixes do not get backported to old Hadoop releases, and the S3A and ABFS connectors are rapidly evolving. New releases will be better, stronger, faster. Generally.
13. If there's a feature/fix on a recent version of hadoop which isn't on the one you are using, you SHALL NOT ask for a backport, unless you want it closed as "invalid please upgrade". After all: it's a free upgrade.
14. You MAY fork your own hadoop/spark/aws sdk versions and cherrypick commits from more recent builds. This is the likely only alternative to upgrade. All commercial vendors of hadoop, spark, iceberg etc do this.
15. If none of this works. a bug report filed on the ASF JIRA server *will get closed as WORKSFORME*. Config issues aren't treated as code bugs

Finally: the ASF documentation: [The S3A Connector](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/).

Note: that link is to the latest release. If you are using an older release it will lack features. Upgrade before complaining that the s3a connector doesn't do what the documentation says it does.

Answer (score 10):

I found stevel's answer above to be extremely helpful.  His information inspired my write-up [here](https://github.com/chriscugliotta/pyspark-s3-windows).  I will copy the relevant parts below.  My answer is tailored to a Python/Windows context, but I suspect most points are still relevant in a JVM/Linux context.

### Dependencies

This answer is intended for Python developers, so it assumes we will install Apache Spark indirectly via pip.  When pip installs PySpark, it collects most dependencies automatically, as seen in `.venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars`.  However, to enable the [S3A Connector](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/), we must track down the following dependencies *manually*:

- JAR file:  `hadoop-aws`
- JAR file:  `aws-java-sdk-bundle`
- Executable:  `winutils.exe` (and `hadoop.dll`) <-- Only needed in Windows

### Constraints

- Assuming we're installing Spark via pip, we can't pick the Hadoop version directly.  We can only pick the PySpark version, e.g. `pip install pyspark==3.1.3`, which will indirectly determine the Hadoop version.  For example, PySpark `3.1.3` maps to Hadoop `3.2.0`.
- All Hadoop JARs must have the *exact* same version, e.g. `3.2.0`.  Verify this with `cd pyspark/jars && ls -l | grep hadoop`.  Notice that `pip install pyspark` automatically included some Hadoop JARs.  Thus, if these Hadoop JARs are `3.2.0`, then we should download `hadoop-aws:3.2.0` to match.
- `winutils.exe` must have the *exact* same version as Hadoop, e.g. `3.2.0`.  Beware, winutils releases are [scarce](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils).  Thus, we must carefully pick our PySpark/Hadoop version such that a matching winutils version exists.  Some PySpark/Hadoop versions *do not have* a corresponding winutils release, thus they cannot be used on Windows.
- `aws-java-sdk-bundle` must be compatible with our `hadoop-aws` choice above.  For example, `hadoop-aws:3.2.0` depends on `aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.375`, which can be verified [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0).

### Instructions

With the above constraints in mind, here is a reliable algorithm for installing PySpark with S3A support on Windows:

1. Find latest available version of `winutils.exe` [here](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils).  At time of writing, it is `3.2.0`.  Place it at `C:/hadoop/bin`.  Set environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` to `C:/hadoop` and (important!) add `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` to `PATH`.
2. Find latest available version of PySpark that uses Hadoop version equal to above, e.g. `3.2.0`.  This can be determined by browsing PySpark's [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.3/pom.xml#L123) file across each release tag.  At time of writing, it is `3.1.3`.
3. Find the version of `aws-java-sdk-bundle` that `hadoop-aws` requires.  For example, if we're using `hadoop-aws:3.2.0`, then we can use [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0).  At time of writing, it is `1.11.375`.
4. Create a venv and install the PySpark version from step 2.

```bash
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/Scripts/activate
pip install pyspark==3.1.3
```

5. Download the AWS JARs into PySpark's JAR directory:

```bash
cd .venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars
ls -l | grep hadoop
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.375/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
```

6. Download winutils:

```bash
cd C:/hadoop/bin
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cdarlint/winutils/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin/winutils.exe
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cdarlint/winutils/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin/hadoop.dll
```

### Testing

To verify your setup, try running the following script.

```py
import pyspark

spark = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
    .appName('my_app')
    .master('local[*]')
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', 'secret')
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', 'secret')
    .getOrCreate())

# Test reading from S3.
df = spark.read.csv('s3a://my-bucket/path/to/input/file.csv')
print(df.head(3))

# Test writing to S3.
df.write.csv('s3a://my-bucket/path/to/output')
```

> You'll need to substitute your AWS keys and S3 paths, accordingly.

> If you recently updated your OS environment variables, e.g. `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH`, you might need to close and re-open VSCode to reflect that.

Comment: nice. getting rid of winutils is something long dreamed of -see HADOOP-13223, "winutils.exe is a bug nexus and should be killed with an axe."