# java.lang.IllegalAccessError Error while reading AWS S3 configuration from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am getting below error when trying to access the configuration from Java.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.streamCounter(S3AInstrumentation.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.streamCounter(S3AInstrumentation.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.<init>(S3AInstrumentation.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at MyProgram.GetHiveTableData(MyProgram.java:710)
    at MyProgram$1.run(MyProgram.java:674)
    at MyProgram$1.run(MyProgram.java:670)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at MyProgram.GetHiveTableDetails(MyProgram.java:670)
    at MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:398)
```

The Code line is

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(uriStr), configuration);
```

uriStr=s3a://sBucketName

*Confurations are set as below for S3A*

```
fs.default.name=fs.defaultFS
fs.defaultFS=s3a://bucketName
sPath: XXXXXX
fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
fs.s3a.access.key=XXXXXX
fs.s3a.secret.key=XXXXXXX
fs.s3a.endpoint=XXXXXXX
hadoop.rpc.protection=privacy
dfs.data.transfer.protection=privacy
hadoop.security.authentication=Kerberos
dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/XXXX@XXXX.XXX.XXXXXX.XXX
yarn.resourcemanager.principal=yarn/XXXX@XXXX.XXX.XXXXXX.XXX
```

Am I missing anything in configuration setup?
Please advise.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution.

Comment: Could you please post the answer here? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Could you please post the solution here . It would be helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem might occurs if the version of aws-sdk and hadoop version is not compatible, you may get more help from [Spark job reading from S3 on Spark cluster gives IllegalAccessError: tried to access method MutableCounterLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527878/spark-job-reading-from-s3-on-spark-cluster-gives-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-ac) and [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411493/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-fs-storagestatistics)

When I roll back `hadoop-aws` version from 2.8.0 to 2.7.3 the problem is solved.

```
spark-submit --master local \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,\
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.6,\
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3 \
test_s3.py
```

According to discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828978/8025086, it seems it is proper to use `aws-java-sdk1.7.4`, I just tested this simple example with pyspark, it also works.  I am not a java guy, may be someone could have a better explanation.

```
# this one also works, notice that the version of aws-java-sdk is different
spark-submit --master local \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,\
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,\
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3 \
test_s3.py
```

Comment: it's mixing the hadoop- jar versions which is causing this specific problem (they are designed to be used in sync), but as the AWS SDK is also a moving target, you should stick with whatever hadoop was built with. 1.7.4 is what Hadoop 2.7.x came with, and is the only one safe to use. 1.10.x? Maybe, but its jackson dependency changed, so you've got new problems. See [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13050](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13050)