# Hadoop 2.9.2, Spark 2.4.0 access AWS s3a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

It's been a couple of days but I could not download from public Amazon Bucket using Spark :(

Here is `spark-shell` command:

```
spark-shell  --master yarn
              -v
              --jars file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.9.2.jar,file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.199.jar
              --driver-class-path=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.199.jar
```

Application started and shell waiting for prompt:

```
   ____              __
  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
   /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_191)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val data1 = sc.textFile("s3a://my-bucket-name/README.md")

18/12/25 13:06:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 242.1 KB, free 246.7 MB)
18/12/25 13:06:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.2 KB, free 246.6 MB)
18/12/25 13:06:40 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on hadoop-edge01:3545 (size: 24.2 KB, free: 246.9 MB)
18/12/25 13:06:40 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at <console>:24
data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = s3a://my-bucket-name/README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> data1.count()

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1168)
... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.StorageStatistics
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 77 more

scala>
```

1. All AWS keys, secret-keys was set in hadoop/core-site.xml as described here: [Hadoop-AWS module: Integration with Amazon Web Services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)
2. The bucket is public - anyone can download (tested with curl -O)
3. All .jars as you can see was provided by Hadoop itself from `/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/` folder
4. There's no additional settings in `spark-defaults.conf` - only what was sent in command line
5. Both jars does not provide this class:

   ```
   jar tf /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.9.2.jar | grep org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
   (no result)

   jar tf /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.199.jar | grep org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
   (no result)
   ```

What should I do ? Did I forget to add another jar ? What the exact configuration of `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk-bundle` ? versions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411493/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-fs-storagestatistics)

Comment: Been there... Even with configuration from the link it does not work with this exception. I need to know exactly versions of all files for this situation. It's not duplicate

Answer (score 17):

Mmmm.... I found the problem, finally..

The main issue is Spark that I have is pre-installed for Hadoop. It's 'v2.4.0 pre-build for Hadoop 2.7 and later'. This is bit of misleading title as you see my struggles with it above. Actually Spark shipped with **different** version of hadoop jars. The listing from: /usr/local/spark/jars/ shows that it have:

> hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
>   hadoop-client-2.7.3.jar
>    ....

it only missing: hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk. I little bit digging in Maven repository: [hadoop-aws-v2.7.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3) and it dependency: [aws-java-sdk-v1.7.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4) and voila ! Downloaded those jar and send *them* as parameters to Spark. Like this:

> spark-shell
>     --master yarn
>     -v
>     --jars file:/home/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,file:/home/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
>     --driver-class-path=/home/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:/home/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar

Did the job !!!

I'm just wondering why all jars from Hadoop (and I send all of them as parameter to --jars and --driver-class-path) didn't catch up. Spark somehow automatically choose it jars and not what I send

Comment: Struggle days until found this answer. The version of hadoop, whether the spark is standalone or with hadoop built-in, the version of hadoop-aws-***, the version of aws-java-sdk-v***. So much dependencies.  Thanks man, you saved my day. Must upvote your question and answer.

Answer (score 9):

I advise you not to do what you did. 
You are running pre built spark with `hadoop 2.7.2` jars on `hadoop 2.9.2` and you added to the classpath some more jars to work with s3 from the `hadoop 2.7.3` version to solve the issue.

What you should be doing is working with a "hadoop free" spark version - and provide the hadoop file by configuration as you can see in the following link - 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/hadoop-provided.html

The main parts:

in `conf/spark-env.sh`

If `hadoop` binary is on your PATH

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

With explicit path to `hadoop` binary

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/path/to/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

Passing a Hadoop configuration directory

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop --config /path/to/configs classpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use spark 2.4.5 and this is what I did and it worked for me. I am able to connect to AWS s3 from Spark in my local.

```
(1) Download spark 2.4.5 from here:https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12.tgz. This spark does not have hadoop in it.
(2) Download hadoop. https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.2.1/hadoop-3.2.1.tar.gz
(3) Update .bash_profile
SPARK_HOME = <SPARK_PATH> #example /home/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12
PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin
(4) Add Hadoop in spark env
Copy spark-env.sh.template as spark-env.sh
add export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(<hadoop_path> classpath)
here <hadoop_path> is path to your hadoop /home/hadoop-3.2.1/bin/hadoop
```