# How to add Hadoop AWS jar to Spark 2.4.5 with JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I was facing an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found` and stumbled upon the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260235/10834788) which works.
However, in the note given right after the answer, the author states the following:

> com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.760 : depends on jdk version hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0: depends on your hadoop version s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: depends on your s3 location

So, when I run the following command:

```
pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.8.0_242,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5
```

I face the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-pom;1.8.0_242: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1302)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

The reason I changed the command is as follows:

1. JDK version:

```
(app-root) java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

2. Pyspark version:
   `2.4.5`
3. Hadoop Version:
   `2.8.5`

How can I resolve this error and start a pyspark shell with the correct dependencies in order to read the files from S3?

Answer (score 2):

The pre-built spark with builtin hadoop poses a problem if any other versions are used and its pretty old. Strongly recommend to use `Hadoop Free build` https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/hadoop-provided.html

The below should work for Spark 2.4.5 with Scala 2.11/2.12.

```
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.659
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.5
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html
- [Hadoop 2.9.2, Spark 2.4.0 access AWS s3a bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922709/hadoop-2-9-2-spark-2-4-0-access-aws-s3a-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for spark:2.4.4-hadoop2.7 :

```
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar --driver-class-path /hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.8.0_242,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5
```

to

```
pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.828,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5
```

1.11.828 is the version of the aws-java-sdk package and not the JDK itself